# how to update information on a popup window while the execution continues

Tags: java, popup, oracle-adf

I have a cancel popup with custom OK button for confirmation and I'd like to update the progress information on it as the execution goes on.

Popup is as follows

```
<af:popup id="confirmationPopupSend" binding="#{pageFlowScope.bean.confirmationPopup}" contentDelivery="immediate">
    <af:dialog id="confirmationDialogSend" modal="true" title="Confirmation" type="cancel">
      <f:facet name="buttonBar">
        <af:commandButton id="confirmDialogButtonSend" text="OK" action="#{pageFlowScope.bean.submitAction}"/>
      </f:facet>
      <af:outputText value="Are you sure? This might take a while."/>
      <af:outputText visible="#{pageFlowScope.bean.someProgress> 0}" 
        value="#{pageFlowScope.bean.someProgress}" />
    </af:dialog>
  </af:popup>
```

My submitAction method is as follows

```
    public String submitAction()
    {
        for(some for condition){
             //update the variable someProgress
             refreshLoadingPopup();
        }
    }
```

and the refresh method

```
public String refreshLoadingPopup(){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
    UIComponent c = findComponent(root, "confirmationDialogSend")
    AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(c);
}
```

The problem here is that refresh method normally works. I checked it by putting a test button on the popup window and it updates the information but when I put the refresh method inside the submitAction method, nothing happens on the popup window as the execution continues. Once the submitAction ends the execution, the popup closes anyway.

I just want to show the progress to the user. 
Any other approach is welcome, too.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the popup simply by calling your `refreshLoadingPopup` method. The following line simply marks the component `c` to be refreshed.

```
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(c);
```

While the request is being processed (the loop in your `submitAction` method is executing) the client will not have a response and component `c` will not be refreshed.

You should continue to update the `pageFlowScope.bean.someProgress` property in your for loop and make the client poll that value i.e. every 0.5 seconds.

You can use af:poll component for this requirement. Here is an example shows how to use af:poll component: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/42-progressbarcolor-169184.pdf

Comment: Your post helped a lot but it still didn't solve it completely. For my case, once the excution starts while the popup is already opened, the popup doesn't get affected by anything whether I make a new thread or render a poll. As far as I see, the way it works is, on the main thread I open only one popup which has the progress indicator in it and do the real execution on a background thread. Then wait for the background thread to finish before closing the popup. However, that doesn't help me although I got it figured out :)

Comment: @MGoksu I'm in a similar problem, how did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @GingerHead sorry, it's been more than a year and I quit that job but as far as I remember, I couldn't find a convenient way to solve it and it wasn't a necessary thing so I abandoned the idea, sorry :(

Comment: @GingerHead not for my case

Comment: @MGoksu neither in my case, that is a big fail . . . if you get away from page to do processes nothing will update the page!

Answer (score -1):

You can create a frame for example a JFrame and then create another window up while `f.setVisible(false);` and then just create another JFrame or window

this is my first time trying to help someone i hope this was helpful for you :D

and if you want code use this

`static JFrame f = new JFrame();`
`static JFrame f2 = new JFrame();`

`public static void createDisplay() {
     f.setVisible(true);
     // DO INFORMATION SETTING CRAP HERE
}`

then create another method

`public static void changeDisplay(){
     f.setVisible(false);
     f2.setVisible(true);
}`

Comment: The question is about Oracle ADF which is a web framework. And the example in your answer is about Swing which is irrelevant.